# Populating datagrid1.view with a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

I got a stored procedure in SQL Server I created some inner joins and now how will I populate my datagrid using that stored procedure.

Here is my code that is not working

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "OfficeEquipmentProfile"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = sqlconn

        sqlconn.Open()



        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentProfile")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblDepartment")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblLocation")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentCategory")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblApplication")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblApplicationLicense")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblEquipmentApplication")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentBrand")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentModel")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentServiceOrder")
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "tblOfficeEquipmentPMplan")


        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentProfile")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblDepartment")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblLocation")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentCategory")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblApplication")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblApplicationLicense")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblEquipmentApplication")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentBrand")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentServiceOrder")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentPMplan")

        DataGrid1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("tblOfficeEquipmentProfile, tblDepartment, tblLocation, tblOfficeEquipmentCategory, tblApplication,tblApplicationLicense, tblEquipmentApplication, tblOfficeEquipmentBrand, tblOfficeEquipmentServiceOrder,tblEquipmentPMplan")
        DataGrid1.ReadOnly = True
        'Button1.Enabled = False
        'DataGrid1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect


        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        sqlconn.Close()
```

I just want to display records from the database

Comment: it returned no error, at the same time didnt display any records from the database

Comment: Please show your stored procedure. I cant see parameters you are calling in cmd.parameter

Comment: my stored procedure too long how can i show this?

Comment: what parameter your stored procedure expects? I cant see any parameters while you are calling this stored procedure in your .net code

Comment: kindly send me your email ill send it to you mine is ivan.jerome003@gmail.com

Comment: my email is nandedkar.kiran@gmail.com

Comment: Your storedprocedure should return multiple tables. And you need only one Fill(Dataset). [Look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239450/returning-multiple-tables-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: because i use inner join. it contains many tables combined to show all columns in 1 datagrid

Comment: inner join doesn't return separate tables, but only one with the combined columns from one or more tables. If you expect to have multiple tables returned by the sp you need (inside the sp) a select for each table as the link posted before explains.

Comment: @AshReva, ivan -  You can use the SO chat facility rather than publishing email addresses.

Comment: @APC sorry sir i cant use chat due to low reputation new account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are returning columns from different tables and not multiple tables then you just need this code.

```
 Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
 Command.Connection = Connection
 Command.CommandText = "OfficeEquipmentProfile"
 Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)

 Dim DataSet As DataSet = New DataSet(Command.CommandText)

 sAdapter.Fill(DataSet)
 DataGrid1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0)
```

Comment: DataGrid1.DataBind() not a member of system.windows.forms.datagrid

im using vb.net 2003

Comment: @APC, AshReva Thank you very much! you both help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandText = "OfficeEquipmentProfile"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlconn
sqlconn.Open()

sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
sDs = New DataSet
sAdapter.Fill(sDs)
DataGrid1.DataSource = sDs
```

The storedprocedure return one or more tables, but you don't need to call a Fill for each table. One is enough. Then assign the whole Dataset to the Datasource or, if you return more than one table and need a specific table

```
DataGrid1.DataSource = sDs
DataGrid1.DataMember = "tablename"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
        con.Open()
        Dim dset As New DataSet
        Dim dbind As New BindingSource
        Dim strquery As String
        strquery = "SELECT prod_code, prod_no, prod_suffix, prod_lvl, customer, model, family, company_code, company_name, company_address, running_no, template_code FROM products_tbl  WHERE  template_code = 'n'and company_code = 'YTPL' and prod_no = '" & txt_product.Text & "' and prod_suffix = '" & txt_suffix.Text & "' and prod_lvl = '" & txt_level.Text & "'"
        Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(strquery, con)
        dset = New DataSet
        adap.Fill(dset)
        dbind.DataSource = dset.Tables(0)
        dg.DataSource = dbind
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Trace No 3: System Error or Data Error!" + Chr(13) + ex.Message + Chr(13) + "Please Contact Your System Administrator!", vbInformation, "Message")
    End Try
```