# how to get data from multiple tables in a single stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

i have three tables table1, table2, and table3. And following is my stored procedure. after executing the stored procedure i got the following out put.

```
alter PROCEDURE test

    @SDate datetime,
    @EDate datetime

As

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Select count(quoteid) as TotalQuote, sum(totalamount) as QuoteAmount from dbo.QuoteBase
    where CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate

    select  count(salesorderid)as TotalOrders, sum(totalamount) as OrderAmount from dbo.SalesOrderBase Where
    CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate

    select count(opportunityid)as TotalSales  from dbo.OpportunityBase Where
    CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate


GO
```

**Output**
[image]

but i don't want to display the query result separately.

How can i done the job so that the query results will be in a single line?

Comment: use a union query. `select ... UNION select ... UNION select ...`

Comment: Here's how to solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239450/returning-multiple-tables-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (Select count(quoteid) as TotalQuote, sum(totalamount) as QuoteAmount from     dbo.QuoteBase where CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate)
CROSS JOIN (select  count(salesorderid)as TotalOrders, sum(totalamount) as OrderAmount from dbo.SalesOrderBase Where CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate)
CROSS JOIN (select count(opportunityid)as TotalSales  from dbo.OpportunityBase Where
CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate)
```

OR easier,

just do a:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3
```

where table1,2 and 3 are your selects.

Hope it helps