# SQL Select Multiple table at onces

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was thinking is there a query that can select many table at once?. Not using a `JOINS`. I tried to research about it but all I got is

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN (parameter1,parameter2);
```

I tried this kind of query

```
select * from Table Table1,Table2
```

but the result is getting from the Table1 only.

All tables are not it relation with each other so it means they are different table to each. What I am trying to do here is I will check the tables if there is a data on it or not. What I was using is query it all `one-by-one` using

```
select * from Table
```

again and again. Hope this will explain it.

Comment: try this : select * from Table1,table2,table3...

Comment: @chiragsatapara that query. I try it.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. Why are JOINs not suited for your task? Are the tables identical in structure/column setup? Why can you not type multiple queries (one for each table)?

Comment: @KiRa: Really you are looking for a combined table as output, or separate tables? If combined you can use chirag satapara' s solution. else write each select statement separately, and you can retrieve them to DataSet.

Comment: @gjijo seperately.

Comment: Then you can write it SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2; In c# code you can use DataSet to hold them and can access each table separately using index as .Table[index]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239450/returning-multiple-tables-from-a-stored-procedure  may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### For combined Tables as an output:

> UNION

To allow duplicate values, use:

> UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM table1 

UNION 

SELECT * FROM table2
```

### For separated Tables as an output:

> DataSet

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("table1");
DataTable table2 = new DataTable("table2");
dataSet.Tables.Add(table1);
dataSet.Tables.Add(table2);
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1;SELECT * from table2", con))
{
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dataSet.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, table1, table2);
    }
}
```

Now you can work with the DataSet's Tables like this ([msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
private void PrintRows(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // For each table in the DataSet, print the row values.
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQL command `UNION`. Then you can make something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2;
```