# How to retrive multiple data tables from sql using c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, datatable, sqldataadapter

I encounter a problem.
I have a generic function that executes stored procedures via connection to my sql DB.
In all SP I need only one dataTable to be returned.

```
   public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string SpName, bool byStoredProce, string[] Searchparam, DataTable dt)
        {

            oDataTable = null;
            oex = null;

            try
            {

                oDataTable = new DataTable(Convert.ToString(globalParm.cntDataTable));
                objCmd = new SqlCommand(SpName.ToString(), oConn);
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (!byStoredProce)
                {
                    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SpName.ToString(), oConn)) // 
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    fillData(SpName, ref Searchparam, cmd, dt);
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(oDataTable);
                }



            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                

            }
            return oDataTable;

        }
```

I added a new sql SP that retrives 2 data tables.
What the best modification for the function above to get any number of data tables ?
When I run this new SP, oDataTable contains the first (between two) of the returned datatables.

Comment: You need `DataSet` [Returning multiple tables from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239450/returning-multiple-tables-from-a-stored-procedure)